# User Defined function not recognized

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a function in VBA that modifies the current VLOOKUP to return nothing instead of `#N/A` when a value is not found. The function works fine when I have it saved in a module in my active workbook but when I move it to my `.xlam` project the output is always `#NAME?`. I should also note that autocomplete does find the function when I begin typing it in a cell.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Function NAVLOOKUP(val As Variant, rng As Range, ofst As Integer) As Variant
    Dim temp As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(val, rng, ofst, False)
    If IsEmpty(temp) Then
        NAVLOOKUP = ""
    Else
        NAVLOOKUP = temp
    End If

End Function
```

It's pretty straightforward so I'm not sure what the problem is. I also made a dummy function in the same `.xlam` project that just adds an "S" to any value and it has been working with no problem.

```
Function ADDS(val As Variant) As String
    ADDS = val & "S"
End Function
```

Since the second function works I am at a loss here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just wrap the standard Vlookup in `IFERROR(...,"")` Where `...` is your VLOOKUP formula?

Comment: The answer is that you will need to tell Excel the workbook in which the UDF resides.  So if it was name Personal.xlam, your cell formula would be `=Personal.xlam!NAVLOOKUP(...)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Since it's a problem I run into on almost a daily basis I've just been looking for a workaround. `=Personal.xlam!NAVLOOKUP(...)` does work but I'd like to avoid the reference if I can. It seems like it should be possible since the `ADDS(...)` function doesn't require it.

Comment: That is understandable. But now that you are moving the UDF to a different workbook `IFERROR(,"")` may be less typing, depending on the name of your workbook.

Comment: Are you sure that ADDS does not exist in a module attached to the sheet also?  It should not work.

Comment: I don't think `IsEmpty` is ever going to be `True` here. `IsEmpty` verifies the type of a `Variant` variable and returns true if that's `Empty` - i.e. an empty/uninitialized `Variant` (this happens to also be the type returned by the value of a cell without any formula or value). Use I think you meant to use `IsError(temp)`, which returns `True` when the expression returns an Excel error (e.g. `#NA` or `#VALUE!`).

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, it's only in the `.xlam` project. I'm not sure if it makes a difference but I added the project by going to `file -> options -> Add-Ins -> Manage Excel Add-Ins -> Go -> ` then browsing for the file and checking the box where it says Add-Ins available.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I actually had to use `IsEmpty` in this case because without the error handling the function is automatically exited when the VLOOKUP returns `#N/A` so it doesn't get a chance to assign a value to `temp`. This way, if there is an error the line where `temp` is assigned it is essentially skipped over and therefore empty.

Comment: Oh you're right, I missed `On Error Resume Next` here; that indeed leaves `temp` an empty `Variant`, so `IsEmpty` is correct. FWIW you should have `Err.Clear` and `On Error GoTo 0` on the lines immediately following the VLOOKUP worksheet function call.

Comment: You can skip the On Error line.  Remove WorkSheetFunction. from the vlookup and then test if temp is an error with iserror(temp).  The application. form of Vlookup will allow the error to pass to the variable without stopping the code.  It is personal preference.  As to the other I am not sure why it works one way but not another, Sorry.

Comment: @ScottCraner `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` is an early-bound call; `Application.VLookup` is late-bound, so it's a little bit more than just personal preference - you only get IntelliSense and compile-time validation on early-bound calls. Also be careful when using named arguments on late-bound functions: `?Application.Sum(Arg1:=2, Arg1=:42)` outputs 1, no error thrown at runtime *or* compile time.

Comment: @Mat'sMug thanks, Early/Late Binding is something I am still trying to wrap my head around.

Comment: @J_Lard I just added your code to my own xlam and added the addon to another sheet, and I was able to use your code without issue and without the needed workbook precursor.  I am not sure why your does not work.  You might want to try open a new workbook and attach the addon.  Then try it in the fresh instance.

Comment: @ScottCraner Wow... that actually worked. I wish I had tried that earlier. Thanks for your help.